# Native workaround for Lead Scoring within Marketing Cloud and Sales cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, sales-cloud, einstein-recommendations, tracking

Basically, I am trying to make something similar to this in marketing could to enable web tracking: https://community.hubspot.com/t5/HubSpot-Ideas/OR-operator-for-lead-score-property/idi-p/291421

There is a similar option for purchase here that has the functionality desired:  https://www.saleswingsapp.com/predictive-lead-scoring-website-tracking-marketing-cloud/

But the functionality is not native. Was thinking of adding collect tracking code and taking website tracking from there over to sales cloud to then create flows to determine lead scores based on urls.

Any thoughts/feedback? Curious if anyone else has tried to achieve something like this before using the collect tracking code.

Comment: Please remember to mark my answers as accepted, [as described here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), for the benefit of the community

Answer (score 0):

I would consider doing this with Einstein Web Recommendations. Once you manage to configure the tracking itself, the data starts flowing into below data extensions:

[image]

- **IGO_PROFILES**: Mapping between the native uuid of Einstein Recommendations and whatever identifier you provide in setUserInfo call. The provided identifier will always reside in the email field. The customer’s profile will also store what the algorithm has determined are the top five attributes for which the customer has the highest affinity. This top five is updated at the end of every user session.
- **IGO_VIEWS**: Stores information on when specific products were viewed
- **IGO_PURCHASES**: Stores information on when specific products were purchased
- **IGO_PRODUCTS**: Contains basic information on products
- **IGO_PRODUCTATTRIBS**: Full metadata on products, derived from catalogue
  import
- **PI_CONTENTVIEWS**: Stores information on when specific articles/non-product pages were viewed
- **PI_CONTENT**: Contains basic information on articles
- **PI_CONTENTATTRIBS**: Full metadata on articles, derived from catalogue import

We have the ability to see all data coming in to our data extensions, available for processing. In IGO_PROFILES, we find the identifying attribute (in email column) and a number of calculated affinities can be seen (In Value_X and Attribute_X columns). These are based on internal calculations in Einstein Recommendations, and cannot be altered – hence we have no control which metadata will be selected for affinity calculation.

Do not use email address, but rather a hashed identifier when using setUserInfo call, as providing PII in plain text on a website is not recommended.

It is a very ”quick and dirty” way of segmenting consumers, and whenthis DE gets joined with a DE containing opted-in consumers, we can produce a sendable DE with an audience, with a specific affinity.

Having detailed information on every single product visit (IGO_VIEWS) allows us – theoretically, to build more complex segments using SQL to lookup e.g. categories in IGO_PRODUCTATTRIBS. However, the volume of the records can make it impractical, and at times close to impossible.

These data extensions can be easily used in Automation Studio Queries, to build audiences based on e.g. browsed products. The diagram above shows the relationships between the individual data extensions. And since the *ATTRIBS data extensions are working by storing name value pairs, the query to find “emails” of users visiting content where size=Large, would be:

```sql
select email from IGO_PROFILES prof 
where prof.user_id in 
(
select user_id from PI_CONTENTVIEWS cv 
inner join PI_CONTENTATTRIBS ca 
on cv.content_id = ca.content_id 
where ca.AttribName = 'size' 
and ca.AttribValue = 'Large'
)
```

And remember, email is NOT email, but the value you have passed in the setUserInfo call in your tracking code.

Once you have identified the segments, you can use e.g. SSJS or Journey Builder to update this data into Sales Cloud.